# How can I disable coupons for a particular order item (or the entire order, if needed)?

Tags: orders, coupon, coupon-codes

We have an extension which can lower the price on specific items for specific customers (using `setCustomPrice()` on the quote_item).

When we utilize this extension we would like to disable coupons--ideally just for the item with the custom price; however disabling it for the entire order would be suitable as well.

How would I go about marking a particular order item, or entire order, as invalid for coupons?

Answer (score 1):

Just modfiy your coupon in the 'shoppingcart price rules'

edit your coupon in 'conditions' tab

adding a rule with 'Product attribute combination', and select 'SKU', select 'is not' put your target SKU which you don't want apply the coupon.

for example if your sku is 'ABCxx123', the rule would looks like
'SKU is not ABCxx123'